# Restarting vs Building a Container on Docker

Tags: deployment, docker, lxc

I have some difficulties understanding when to restart a container and when to build a new one.

Imagine I have a webapp whose data I give to a container (over a symbolic link which point to the current deploy). Now I have two options when a new deploy comes in: (1) build a new container from an image or (2) simply restart the running container.

I know that the decision depends on various things but my question is a more conceptual one:

What is generally a better practice or how is Docker meant to be used? Do you see any problems with one of these approaches?

Answer (score 0):

I think that both options can have the same result in some cases.

Anyway, I think that the correct approach is to prepare an image with all your prerequisites and dependencies. This is your **inital state** that you want to use for your webapp. Then you can start your webapp in one or many containers based on this same image. Every instance has own unique container.

In case of deploy I think that you should do a "fresh start": stop and discard running container and create a new container with your new deployed app.

Sure, you can just restart the container, but every container has a state and - in general - you want to throw this state away and start again with your fresh initial image. Of course, if your app just printfs "Hello World", there is no state saved in container, so in this case both options behave the same.